# Python basic string array

Tags: python

Can anybody explain me this: `s[81:67:-1]`

When `s` is "`this is me asking a question on stackoverflow.com and hoping to get an answer that will help me further`"

Comment: docs can — http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Comment: Sorry for dup, I just did not know how to call this method. Now I know: "slice notation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is accessing string in reverse. From 81st character, till 67th character. The step value is -1. If you specify a positive value, you ll get nothing.

```
print s[81:67:-1]
print s[81:67:1]
```

**Output**

```
taht rewsna na
```

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings). It is called slicing notation.

Comment: Will it return the string in reverse? Or is it the same as `s[67:81]`

Comment: thx @thefourtheye, will accept your answer when I can ^^
must say that python is beautiful, maybe I'll try & learn it.

Comment: @grmbl It will return the string in reverse, as you guessed.

Comment: @grmbl Indeed, it is. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the element from position 81 to 67  but in reverse order (:-1 achieve this)

So, you are iterating over elements from position 67 to 81.